# Two data frame Name mapping and replace a values base on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames (df) one equally divided into weeks by count of the week for the month(February 4 weeks March 5 weeks). The other one has actual data.

equally divided df

```py
Name        Feb_1   Feb_2   Feb_3   Feb_4   Mar_5   Mar_6   Mar_7   Mar_8   Mar_9
Sunil       0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Amaya       0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Will        0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Francis     0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Kadeep      0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Hima        0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Lazy        0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Joseph      0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
```

actual df

```py
Name        Feb_1   Feb_2   Feb_3   Feb_4   Mar_5   Mar_6   Mar_7   Mar_8   Mar_9
Sunil       0.2     0.4     0.3     0.1     0       0       0       0       0
Hima        0.5     0.2     0.3     0       0.2     0.3     0.2     0.2     0.1
Kamal       0.3     0       0.5     0.2     0.1     0.5     0.1     0.1     0.2
Amaya       0.5     0       0.3     0.2     0       0       0       0       0
Jacob       0.2     0.4     0       0.4     0.4     0       0.2     0.2     0.2
Preety      0.7     0.1     0.1     0.1     0.2     0.1     0.4     0.3     0
Will        0.8     0.2     0       0       0.1     0.2     0.3     0.1     0.3
Francis     0.4     0.2     0.3     0.1     0.2     0.4     0       0.4     0
Tara        0       0.5     0.2     0.3     0.2     0       0.3     0.2     0.3
```

I want to replace the data in equally divided df from the actual df. Condition for the week 1 to 4 (Feb) is if the actual df week 1 to 4 sum = 1. For example.

actual df
Sunil 0.2   + 0.4   +   0.3 +   0.1 = 1

Then replace the number in equally divided df. So Sunil     0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25 will replace with the above values.

Week 5-9 is the same. If some of the values in actual df = 1 then replace.
So for Sunil, it's 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 not equal to 1 So not replace the values for weeks 5 to 9.

So the data frame looks like the below.

equally divided with edit df

```py
Name        Feb_1   Feb_2   Feb_3   Feb_4   Mar_5   Mar_6   Mar_7   Mar_8   Mar_9
Sunil       0.2     0.4     0.3     0.1     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Amaya       0.5     0       0.3     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Will        0.8     0.2     0       0       0.1     0.2     0.3     0.1     0.3
Francis     0.4     0.2     0.3     0.1     0.2     0.4     0       0.4     0
Kadeep      0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Hima        0.5     0.2     0.3     0       0.2     0.3     0.2     0.2     0.1
Lazy        0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Joseph      0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
```

I'm trying to bring all the values from actual df to equally divided frame and going to edit it but couldn't get a way.

```py
equally ['Feb_1_actual'] =  equally ['Name'].map(actual.set_index('Name')['Feb_1'])

## then get a some and if it's equal to 1 replace the value other wise keep the same value
```

Is there another way to do it?
Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is not to deal with variable column name as it can't be used with pandas methods. So we need to unpivot them first through `pd.melt`, perform complex grouping, and then pivot back

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

# Read data
text = """Name        Feb_1   Feb_2   Feb_3   Feb_4   Mar_5   Mar_6   Mar_7   Mar_8   Mar_9
Sunil       0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Amaya       0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Will        0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Francis     0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Kadeep      0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Hima        0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Lazy        0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2
Joseph      0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2"""

column_names = [x.split() for x in text.split("\n")][0]
values = [x.split() for x in text.split("\n")][1:]
equally = pd.DataFrame(
    values, columns=column_names
).assign(**{k: partial(lambda key, df: df[key].astype(np.float64), k) for k in column_names[1:]})

text = """Name        Feb_1   Feb_2   Feb_3   Feb_4   Mar_5   Mar_6   Mar_7   Mar_8   Mar_9
Sunil       0.2     0.4     0.3     0.1     0       0       0       0       0
Hima        0.5     0.2     0.3     0       0.2     0.3     0.2     0.2     0.1
Kamal       0.3     0       0.5     0.2     0.1     0.5     0.1     0.1     0.2
Amaya       0.5     0       0.3     0.2     0       0       0       0       0
Jacob       0.2     0.4     0       0.4     0.4     0       0.2     0.2     0.2
Preety      0.7     0.1     0.1     0.1     0.2     0.1     0.4     0.3     0
Will        0.8     0.2     0       0       0.1     0.2     0.3     0.1     0.3
Francis     0.4     0.2     0.3     0.1     0.2     0.4     0       0.4     0
Tara        0       0.5     0.2     0.3     0.2     0       0.3     0.2     0.3"""
column_names = [x.split() for x in text.split("\n")][0]
values = [x.split() for x in text.split("\n")][1:]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    values, columns=column_names
).assign(**{k: partial(lambda key, df: df[key].astype(np.float64), k) for k in column_names[1:]})

# Processing
equally_unpivot = pd.melt(equally, id_vars='Name', value_vars=column_names[1:], var_name='Month_Week', value_name='Val').assign(**{
    "Month": lambda df: df["Month_Week"].str.split("_").str[0],
    "Week": lambda df: df["Month_Week"].str.split("_").str[1],
})

df_unpivot = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Name', value_vars=column_names[1:], var_name='Month_Week', value_name='Val').assign(**{
    "Month": lambda df: df["Month_Week"].str.split("_").str[0],
    "Week": lambda df: df["Month_Week"].str.split("_").str[1],
})

valid_entries = df_unpivot[["Name", "Month", "Val"]].groupby(["Name", "Month"], as_index=False).sum().query("Val == 1").drop(columns=["Val"])

merged_df = (
    equally[["Name"]].merge(
        pd.concat([
            equally_unpivot.merge(
                valid_entries,
                on=["Name", "Month"],
                how="left",
                indicator=True
            ).query("_merge == 'left_only'").drop(columns=["_merge"]),
            df_unpivot.merge(
                valid_entries,
                on=["Name", "Month"],
                how="inner",
            )
        ])
        .drop(columns=["Month", "Week"])
        .pivot(index="Name", columns="Month_Week", values="Val")
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index(drop=False)
    )
)

print(merged_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise approach:

- splitting dataframes in 2 segments `Feb` and `Mar`
- arrange them by matched `Name` column
- update each segment with [`pd.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) and finally concat them

---

```
eq_Feb = eq_df.set_index('Name').filter(like='Feb')
eq_Mar = eq_df.set_index('Name').filter(like='Mar')
actual_df_ = actual_df[actual_df.Name.isin(eq_df.Name)]
actual_Feb = actual_df_.set_index('Name').filter(like='Feb')
actual_Mar = actual_df_.set_index('Name').filter(like='Mar')

eq_Feb.update(actual_Feb[actual_Feb.sum(1).astype(int).eq(1.0)])
eq_Mar.update(actual_Mar[actual_Mar.sum(1).astype(int).eq(1.0)])
res_df = pd.concat([eq_Feb, eq_Mar], axis=1)
```

---

```
         Feb_1  Feb_2  Feb_3  Feb_4  Mar_5  Mar_6  Mar_7  Mar_8  Mar_9
Name                                                                  
Sunil     0.20   0.40   0.30   0.10    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2
Amaya     0.50   0.00   0.30   0.20    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2
Will      0.80   0.20   0.00   0.00    0.1    0.2    0.3    0.1    0.3
Francis   0.40   0.20   0.30   0.10    0.2    0.4    0.0    0.4    0.0
Kadeep    0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2
Hima      0.50   0.20   0.30   0.00    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2
Lazy      0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2
Joseph    0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2
```